# Parallax Scrolling--Image not behind

Tags: javascript, parallax

So I am new to JavaScript and especially parallax scrolling. But I tried to follow a basic tutorial to learn and two things aren't working:

(1) The second background image in which the parallax scrolling is to effect isn't going behind the text.``
(2) The parallax scrolling isn't even working which may have to do with the fact that the image is somehow on the same layer as the text even though it's in a totally different div tag.

I am a beginner so please help.

Here's a link to the whole code:

```
(http://codepen.io/allon-z/pen/JXqBNL?editors=1100)
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/allon-z/pen/JXqBNL?editors=1100 sorry having trouble with the link

Comment: What is the link for the tutorial?

Comment: Well it's a YouTube video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=D75WTf_Y738 I just replaced the images and made minor image positioning adjustments because I don't have the images he uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the javascript. You can add it by using `script` tags in the head or body.

```
<script>
  function parallax(){
    var prlx_lyr_1 = document.getElementById('prlx_lyr_1');
    var prlx_lyr_2 = document.getElementById('prlx_lyr_2');
    prlx_lyr_1.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+'px';
    prlx_lyr_2.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 8)+'px';
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
</script>
```

Snippet:

```js
  function parallax(){
    var prlx_lyr_1 = document.getElementById('prlx_lyr_1');
    var prlx_lyr_2 = document.getElementById('prlx_lyr_2');
    prlx_lyr_1.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 4)+'px';
    prlx_lyr_2.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset / 8)+'px';
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", parallax, false);
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0px;
  position:relative;
}

#content_layer{
  position: absolute;
  height: 32000px;
}

#prlx_lyr_1{
  position: fixed;
  background: url(https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/shape_highlights_circles_light_47468_3840x2400.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}

#prlx_lyr_2{
  position: fixed;
  background: url(http://space-facts.com/wp-content/uploads/venus-transparent.png) no-repeat 0px 100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="prlx_lyr_1"></div>
  <div id="prlx_lyr_2"></div>
  <div id="content_layer">
    <h2>About Me</h2>
    <p>Hi! I am a web developper that focuses on fast, responsive web development. I am proficient in JavaScript, PHP, Databases, SQL, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and much more. Check out some of my websites!</p>

    <h2>Porfolio</h2>
    <p>Hi! I am a web developper that focuses on fast, responsive web development. I am proficient in JavaScript, PHP, Databases, SQL, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and much more. Check out some of my websites!</p>

    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p>Hi! I am a web developper that focuses on fast, responsive web development. I am proficient in JavaScript, PHP, Databases, SQL, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and much more. Check out some of my websites!</p>

    <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <p>Hi! I am a web developper that focuses on fast, responsive web development. I am proficient in JavaScript, PHP, Databases, SQL, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and much more. Check out some of my websites!</p>

    <h2>My Webiste Links</h2>
    <p>Hi! I am a web developper that focuses on fast, responsive web development. I am proficient in JavaScript, PHP, Databases, SQL, HTML, CSS, Bootstrap, and much more. Check out some of my websites!</p>

    <h2>More Gibberish</h2>
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse sollicitudin tempus odio, sed vulputate quam molestie ornare. Sed et risus felis. Donec aliquet suscipit urna quis facilisis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Cras auctor orci eros, non fringilla enim tempus sit amet. Aliquam et cursus massa. Donec urna magna, blandit id eros quis, pretium eleifend augue. Ut blandit neque arcu, vitae placerat lacus volutpat eget. Praesent suscipit nulla leo, ut eleifend est auctor ac. Vivamus ut arcu pulvinar, vulputate ipsum ac, sodales elit.

    Cras interdum ligula magna, eu mollis   leo sagittis tristique. Ut semper arcu non tristique posuere. Nullam efficitur purus ac nibh congue, sed sollicitudin nisi sodales. Nullam consectetur at lorem vitae congue. Phasellus condimentum gravida leo, sed maximus neque eleifend eget. Duis at leo purus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Etiam porta non ante eget pulvinar. Donec in urna non velit accumsan auctor eu vel ipsum. Phasellus interdum id dolor a venenatis. Aliquam facilisis lacinia justo, vitae porta mi ornare eget. Donec et sollicitudin nisl. Mauris dignissim consequat magna at ornare. Vestibulum at dolor turpis.

    Mauris tristique tellus leo, at porttitor urna tincidunt id. Pellentesque nec iaculis tortor. Aenean maximus justo ac enim pellentesque gravida. Cras ullamcorper aliquam nunc quis auctor. Fusce semper dui nec accumsan suscipit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean sed tempor neque. Curabitur porttitor velit vitae nisi pulvinar, in rhoncus erat tempor.

    Nam at sodales arcu. Sed vehicula tortor ut enim molestie consectetur. Sed eu porta nulla. Integer ultricies lorem quis sagittis mattis. Cras vel dui dolor. In feugiat sem quis pellentesque dictum. Nam quis metus justo. Sed non leo arcu. Donec commodo vel purus non semper. Sed viverra nisl at leo finibus, ac mollis ligula vehicula.

    Curabitur dignissim ligula quis velit finibus fringilla. Donec varius consectetur purus, ac consectetur neque pulvinar ac. Donec sit amet leo eget sem maximus tempus quis ac ex. Praesent sapien erat, finibus vel nisi eget, molestie gravida tellus. Donec sapien augue, aliquam id convallis et, vulputate hendrerit est. Curabitur nibh ipsum, pharetra vitae sodales eget, scelerisque eget erat. Nulla nec cursus eros, sed rhoncus sapien. Cras diam quam, pulvinar gravida massa sed, vehicula imperdiet mi. Praesent et ipsum sed sem sodales dapibus. Sed pulvinar dui a sollicitudin fermentum. Nulla faucibus dolor nisl, a pretium nunc laoreet sed. Cras magna odio, fringilla id sagittis ullamcorper, aliquam a orci. Integer convallis id turpis ut sagittis.</p>

  </div>

</body>
```